# [Boost].SML pass guard parameters

Tags: c++, boost, boost-sml

I am getting started with [Boost].SML but i just don't get how to check an variable. I am trying to implement a ATM machine, where you have to put in a Code for getting access. So i was trying this:
Guard

```
    const auto right_PIN = [](int pin){ cout << "PIN VALUE: " << pin << endl;
                                    if(pin == 1234){
                                        return true;
                                    }else{
                                        return false;
                                    }
                                };
```

transition table like this:

```
startState + event [right_PIN]  = rightState,
startState + event [!right_PIN] = wrontState,
```

Now before i process the event i want to pass a parameter to the guard to check if its the right pin.

Is this possible?

Comment: I think I should be able to answer this, but I won't be able to get started without a SSCCE or [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you, but I think I found a solution. Could you maybe review my annswer? Do you need any further information to review it? Thanks in Advance

Comment: Awesome. I find it hard to review the answer without full code, but it's super that posted your own answer so it may help others in the future

Answer (score 1):

I think I found a solution.

At first I declared a struct PIN with a value like this:

```
struct PIN {
    int value{};
};
```

then I updated the guard and implemented it in the struct for implementing the state machine:

```
const auto right_PIN = [](PIN& pin){ cout << "PIN VALUE: " << pin.value << endl;
                                    return pin.value == 1234;
                                };
```

In my main method i created an object of the struct pin and gave it to the state machine:

```
PIN p;
boost::sml::sm<bk> sm{p};
```

Then before processing the event i just updated the value of the PIN:

```
p.value = 1234;
sm.process_event(event());
```